# build warning for kinetic release - "missing whitespace after the macro name"

Tags: ros, jenkins, ros-kinetic, release, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hiho,

while preparing one of our packages for release I encountered a strange problem. While building for ros indigo and jade worked as supposed (no errors), there are warnings for ros kinetic and lunar, which in turn leads to an "unstable" build state. **Before releasing to kinetic, i would like to get rid of the warnings.**

It seems as the warning message *"missing whitespace after the macro name"* is related to some macro passed via command-line:

- e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529540/what-causes-this-missing-whitespace-after-the-macro-name-error

The package is hosted here:

- https://github.com/peterweissig/ros_pcdfilter

The build-results can be found here:

- indigo: http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__pcdfilter_pa__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/
- kinetic: http://build.ros.org/job/Kdev__pcdfilter_pa__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/10/warnings21Result/

Console-Log:
http://build.ros.org/job/Kdev__pcdfilter_pa__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/10/consoleFull

- 12.1. build workspace in isolation and install
- ...
- 00:06:42.344 Scanning dependencies of target pcdfilter_pa
- 00:06:42.361 [  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcdfilter_pa.dir/src/pcdfilter_pa.cpp.o
- 00:06:42.370 **:0:15: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name**
- 00:06:43.034 [  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcdfilter_pa.dir/src/pcdfilter_pa_parameter.cpp.o
- 00:06:43.043 **:0:15: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name**
- 00:06:43.609 [ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcdfilter_pa.dir/src/pcdfilter_pa_filter.cpp.o
- 00:06:43.621 **:0:15: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name**
- ...

In contrast a similar package is build stable for all releases:
https://github.com/peterweissig/ros_parameter

- indigo: http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__parameter_pa__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/
- kinetic: http://build.ros.org/job/Kdev__parameter_pa__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/

Thank you for your help in advance 
Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267994/build-warning-for-kinetic-release---%22missing-whitespace-after-the-macro-name%22/) by [peter](https://answers.ros.org/users/31433/peter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I finally found the core of the problem:
During the make-process the CXX-Flag "-DDISABLE_LIBUSB-1.0" will be set in the file "flags.make". This flag has a bad name as it consists of a "-" Symbol. The file itself was created during the cmake-process based on the added definitions.

The solution was to remove the bad named macro within the "**CMakeLists.txt**" file be adding 
**remove_definitions(-DDISABLE_LIBUSB-1.0)**

See also [link text](https://github.com/peterweissig/ros_pcdfilter/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

Greetings
Peter

---

Originally posted by [peter](https://answers.ros.org/users/31433/peter/) with karma: 26 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1